# cakephp saving data into database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i am new in cake php.I want to insert form data into database.But could not inserted.please help

controller:
officetypesController.php

```
<?php
class OfficetypesController extends AppController {   

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Officetype->create();
            if ($this->Officetype->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data has been saved'));

            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

view

add.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('name');
        //echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('under', array(
            'options' => array('1' => 'HO', '2' => 'RO')
        ));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

model

officetype.php

```
<?php
class  Officetype extends AppModel {


}
```

database:
table name :officetypes ,
fields name :id,name,under

when i click submit button than showing the message "The data could not be saved. Please, try again."

Comment: Any errors? How do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: when i click submit button than showing the message "The data could not be saved. Please, try again."

Comment: I think you copied add.ctp from somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Officetype->create();
        if ($this->Officetype->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data has been saved'));

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Check the database to see if the records are added.

Why is the form related to users if you want to add office types?

```
<div class="office_type form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Officetype'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Office type'); ?></legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('under', array(
            'options' => array('1' => 'HO', '2' => 'RO')
        ));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```